# passing multiple .yml files to docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker noob here. 
I have two files docker-compose.build.yml and docker-compose.up.yml in my docker folder. Following are the contents of both files..

docker-compose.build.yml

```
version: "3"
services:

    base:
        build:
          context: ../
          dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.base
          args:
            DEBUG: "true"
        image: ottertune-base
        labels:
          NAME: "ottertune-base"

    web:
        build:
          context: ../
          dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.web
        image: ottertune-web
        depends_on:
          - base
        labels:
          NAME: "ottertune-web"
        volumes:
          - ../server:/app

    driver:
        build:
          context: ../
          dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.driver
        image: ottertune-driver
        depends_on:
          - base
        labels:
          NAME: "ottertune-driver"
```

docker-compose.up.yml

```
version: "3"
services:

    web:
        image: ottertune-web
        container_name: web
        expose:
          - "8000"
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        links:
          - backend
          - rabbitmq
        depends_on:
          - backend
          - rabbitmq
        environment:
          DEBUG: 'true'
          ADMIN_PASSWORD: 'changeme'
          BACKEND: 'postgresql'
          DB_NAME: 'ottertune'
          DB_USER: 'postgres'
          DB_PASSWORD: 'ottertune'
          DB_HOST: 'backend'
          DB_PORT: '5432'
          DB_OPTS: '{}'
          MAX_DB_CONN_ATTEMPTS: 30
          RABBITMQ_HOST: 'rabbitmq'
        working_dir: /app/website
        entrypoint: ./start.sh
        labels:
          NAME: "ottertune-web"
        networks:
          - ottertune-net


    driver:
        image: ottertune-driver
        container_name: driver
        depends_on:
          - web
        environment:
          DEBUG: 'true'
        working_dir: /app/driver
        labels:
          NAME: "ottertune-driver"
        networks:
          - ottertune-net

    rabbitmq:
        image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
        container_name: rabbitmq
        restart: always
        hostname: "rabbitmq"
        environment:
           RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "guest"
           RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "guest"
           RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"
        expose:
           - "15672"
           - "5672"
        ports:
           - "15673:15672"
           - "5673:5672"
        labels:
           NAME: "rabbitmq"
        networks:
          - ottertune-net

    backend:
        container_name: backend
        restart: always
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'ottertune'
          POSTGRES_DB: 'ottertune'
        expose:
          - "5432"
        ports:
          - "5432:5432"
        labels:
          NAME: "ottertune-backend"
        networks:
          - ottertune-net

networks:
   ottertune-net:
      driver: bridge
```

Nothing wrong with the dockerfiles, i just have a few doubts about this approach.

1. What purpose does having multiple files serve instead of just one docker-compose.yml?
2. How does docker-compose work when used with multiple files?
3. When i do `docker-compose -f docker-compose.build.yml build --no-cache`

```
Building base
Step 1/1 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
---> 775349758637
[Warning] One or more build-args [DEBUG] were not consumed
Successfully built 775349758637
Successfully tagged ottertune-base:latest
Building web
Step 1/1 : FROM ottertune-base
---> 775349758637
Successfully built 775349758637
Successfully tagged ottertune-web:latest 
Building driver
Step 1/1 : FROM ottertune-base
---> 775349758637
Successfully built 775349758637
Successfully tagged ottertune-driver:latest
```

and then `docker-compose up` i get the error

```
rabbitmq is up-to-date                                                                                                                                                                       
backend is up-to-date                                                                                                                                                                        Starting web ... error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: 
starting container process caused "exec: \"./start.sh\": stat ./start.sh: no such file or 
directory": unknown                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: 
starting container process caused "exec: \"./start.sh\": stat ./start.sh: no such file or 
directory": unknown                                                                                                                                                                                
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

this entrypoint start.sh is defined in the docker-compose.up.yml file which I didn't pass as an argument to

`docker-compose build`

So, why is the `docker-compose up` trying to run this entrypoint from a yml file which is not even passed during build? Really confused on this and didn't find much about it on google and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you `docker-compose -f a.yml -f b.yml ...`, [Docker Compose merges the two YAML files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files).  If you look at the two files you've posted, one has all of the run-time settings (`ports:`, `environment:`, ...), and if you happened to have the images already it would be enough to run the application.  The second *only* has build-time settings (`build:`), but requires the source tree checked out locally to be able to run.

You probably need to specify both files on every `docker-compose` invocation

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.build.yml -f docker-compose.up.yml up --build
```

It does seem like the author of these files intended for them to be run separately

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.build.yml build
docker-compose -f docker-compose.up.yml up
```

but note that some of the run-time options in the build file, like `volumes:` to hide the application built into the image, will never take effect.

(You should be able to delete a large number of settings in the "up" YAML file that either duplicate what's in the image or that Docker Compose can provide for you: `container_name:`, `expose:`, `links:`, `working_dir:`, `entrypoint:`, `networks:`, and (probably) `labels:` are all unnecessary and can be deleted.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this does clear my confusion. The `volumes:` option not taking effect is also a problem. Please elaborate that part as why it is ignored and how can i use the `volumes:` option.

Comment: It only has an effect during the `docker-compose up` step, so if you run `build` separately, it has no effect there.  Its real effect is to hide the code in the image and replace it with arbitrary content from your host system; I’d just delete it entirely.

Comment: actually the `volumes:` option didn't exist in the original file and I added it later on cause I want to use it as a development environment. I added it to the docker-compose.up.yml with all other run-time options and then doing 
'docker-compose -f docker-compose.build.yml build`
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.up.yml up` and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

> What purpose does having multiple files serve instead of just one docker-compose.yml?

You can share configuration across environments. For example, I keep the common configuration such as the network and server in a `docker-compose.yml`. I keep my development environment specifics such as a server with automatic reload and debugging enabled in a `docker-compose.override.yml`. I keep the production-specific configs in a `docker-compose.prod.yml`. Then I can run `docker-compose up --build` for my development environment (Docker Compose uses `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` by default). And I can run my prod environment with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --build`. You can read about this in the dedicated [docs page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).

> How does docker-compose work when used with multiple files?

It takes the first file as the base file, and adds or replaces configs from subsequent files ot the base file. See the [relevant docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#adding-and-overriding-configuration).

> When i do docker-compose -f docker-compose.build.yml build --no-cache ...

As for your last question, I can't really tell by what I've seen. But unlike `Dockerfile`s which need two commands (`docker build` and `docker run`), `docker-compose` only needs one. So when you do `docker-compose up`, it looks for a file named `docker-compose.yml` (and also `docker-compose.override.yml` if it's present).

Comment: since none of my docker files are named  either docker-compose.yml or docker-compose.override.yml, how do i build and then up form those files? What I currently do is  `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --build` and then `docker-compose up`. Should i pass the yml files to `docker-compose up` too?

Comment: You only need to run the command once (i.e., `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --build`). What you're doing currently is running Docker Compose twice, once with only `docker-compose.prod.yml` and then again with only `docker-compose.yml`.