# Passing multiple compose files in **docker compose** using single -f flag

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker noob here.

I have a docker directory at project root. It contains some docker compose files, say, `docker-compose-{1..5}.yml`. I want to run `docker compose up` (Note: not `docker-compose`). Searching docker documentation, SO, Internet, all I can find is references to run as in

```sh
$ project_root/docker: docker-compose -f docker-compose-1.yml -f docker-compose-2.yml -f docker-compose-2.yml up
```

However, while trying help doc for `docker compose` shows

```sh
$: docker compose --help

Usage:  docker compose [OPTIONS] COMMAND

Docker Compose

Options:
      --ansi string                Control when to print ANSI control characters ("never"|"always"|"auto") (default "auto")
      --env-file string            Specify an alternate environment file.
  -f, --file stringArray           Compose configuration files
      --profile stringArray        Specify a profile to enable
      --project-directory string   Specify an alternate working directory
                                   (default: the path of the Compose file)
  -p, --project-name string        Project name

Commands:
  build       Build or rebuild services
  .
  .
  .
  up          Create and start containers

Run 'docker compose COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.
```

**MY QUERY IS**

How to pass multiple files to `docker compose` in one go using single `-f` flag as mentioned in doc using `stringArray`? What is the format?

I tried, but no success:

```sh
$: docker compose -f "file1.yml" "file2.yml" up   # nope
 
$: docker compose -f ["file1.yml" "file2.yml"] up   # nope 

$: docker compose -f ["file1.yml", "file2.yml"] up   #nope

$: docker compose -f {"file1.yml" "file2.yml"} up   #nope

$: docker compose -f ("file1.yml" "file2.yml") up   #nope

# and some other combinations thereof.
```

EDIT#1:

I had checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59391408/passing-multiple-yml-files-to-docker-compose) but it does not answer my query. I am specifically looking for passing multiple string values (my compose files path) to the command `docker compose` using a single `-f` flag, much like - *hey compose, I got these files and I want you to run these* rather than *run this, run this, run this*.

Now I am confused if it is even possible or I have to use multiple `-f` one for each file. But the help doc should not mention then

```sh
Usage:  docker compose [OPTIONS] COMMAND

Docker Compose

Options:
  -f, --file stringArray           Compose configuration files  # <-- It says files here
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passing multiple .yml files to docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59391408/passing-multiple-yml-files-to-docker-compose)

Comment: @Victor Exactly my point. Don't want to use multiple `-f` flags as mentioned. As per doc, a single `-f` flag with stringArray should work and I am looking for that particular pattern.

Comment: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-debug.yml up` works as i expect

`docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-debug.yml up` 

does not and, as the OP points out, none of the attempts at guessing what format a stringArray might be work. Using COMPOSE_FILE also did not produce the expected behaviour with `docker compose`

Comment: i've just updated docker to 20.10.7 (from 20.10.6) and multiple docker compose files now seems to work as expected using the form `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-debug.yml up`.

Comment: I was getting unexpected behavior because I simply put configuration in a file that was not passed with `-f` when I meant to put the configuration in a different file that was passed with `-f`. With multiple compose files it's easy to get confused, so doublecheck.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the `COMPOSE_FILE` environment variable while specifying multiple compose files in it:

```
COMPOSE_FILE
Specify the path to a Compose file. If not provided, Compose looks for a file named docker-compose.yml in the current directory and then each parent directory in succession until a file by that name is found.

This variable supports multiple Compose files separated by a path separator (on Linux and macOS the path separator is :, on Windows it is ;). For example: COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.yml:docker-compose.prod.yml. The path separator can also be customized using COMPOSE_PATH_SEPARATOR.
```

Source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/

Comment: You can't use a single `-f` option. You have to introduce a new one for each yaml.

Comment: With this you don't need to use the `-f` option at all.

Comment: Thanks @Victor. This work around is ok. It's a valid solution, I must agree. But my question was regarding usage of `-f` option.

Comment: As @AntonioPetricca pointed out and per the documentation, I think that you can't do that:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files
Maybe you are looking to an old version?