# How can I run two different docker.compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

currently I'am working on two project and these projects have different docker compose files but when I run `docker compose up -d` command it doesn't run correct containers. I mean

If I run docker compose in **x** project. It stil up containers belongs to **b** project running. How can I fix this issue. Thank you.

I Tried

docker compose up -

```
docker compose up -d --remove-orphans
```

Comment: Does this answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59391408/passing-multiple-yml-files-to-docker-compose

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]; at least give examples of the skeletons of the `docker-compose.yml` files, the directory layout, and the specific commands you're running?  In a Compose context the name of the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml` file turns out to be important as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run them simultaneously - Try to use different names and ports for the containers/services.

If you want to run them at different occasions -

Stop previous project with `docker-compose down` then start other with `docker-compose up --force-recreate --remove-orphans -d`

To persist the use volumes declaration the docker-compose. for example observe the `cms-content` in below snippet

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  web:
    image: ghost:latest
    ports:
      - "2368:2368"
    volumes:
      - cms-content:/var/lib/ghost/content
volumes:
  cms-content:
```

Comment: thank you this is solved my problem but when run --force-recreate command all my data getting lost.

Comment: @AkifKara above answer has been modified to resolve your query.